# How can I change selected textBox in windowsForms app

Tags: c#, winforms

I want users to be able to travel between textboxes and to a button by clicking  `Keys.Enter`,  `Keys.Up`,  `Keys.Down`. Is there a way like `this.SelectedItem = TxtBoxName` or something?

```
    private void TxtBoxName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if(TextIsEmpty(TxtBoxDebt.Text))
            {
                //switch to TxtBoxDebt
            }
            else
            {
                AssignNewPerson();
            }
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            //switch to TxtBoxDebt
        }
    }
    private void TxtBoxDebt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            AssignNewPerson();
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            //switch to TxtBoxName
        }
        else if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            //switch to TxtBoxNote
        }
    }
    private void TxtBoxNote_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            AssignNewPerson();
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            //switch to TxtBoxDebt
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            //switch to BtnAssign
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tab is the standard way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the Focus() method, for example:

```
TxtBoxDebt.Focus();
```